# Electron - IPC module not sending data to main from renderer

Tags: javascript, electron, ipc

I'm new to Electron and am trying to send a variable from a renderer process file to the main using an IPC module.  I am seeing in the Devtron panel that the IPC message is being send out from the renderer but it shows no signs of having been received in main.js.  I suspect the issue may have to be with how the files are linked together; I'm calling the renderer file from a linked script tag in the index.html but expecting the renderer file (in this case, keycapture.js) to send directly to main.js, and I'm not sure that's how this works.

Here are the segments of code that give and send the IPC message:

main.js:

```
app.on('ready',function(){

  //Set up a listener for what I've done in keycapture (in the renderer process)

      //???
  ipc.on('invokeAction', function(event, args){
    console.log("RECEIVED IPC IN MAIN!")
    var hotkey = args;
    console.log(hotkey);
    //var result = processData(data);
    //event.sender.send('actionReply', result);
    //Alright, time to test and troubleshoot.  
  });
```

keycapture.js (linked from index.html which main.js loads in):

```
function keyCancel(ev){
        /*******
        Use IPC to send the data back to Main to pass on to the local appData file

        Modify the below code to fit with what I'm trying to do.
        *******/

        ipcRenderer.send('invokeAction', hotkey);
        //Remove focus from the input field
        $(input).blur();
         return;
      }
```

Comment: Looks like it should work, can you please show how you are setting up the ipc?

Comment: Hmmm... what do you mean?  This is the IOC section, and I require the IPC components in their respective file headers...

Comment: In main.js should that not be ipcMain.. ?

Comment: The issue seems to be that main.js is throwing an error earlier on by not recognizing the property of 'on'.  I'll be creating a new issue regarding this.

Comment: `const {
 ipcMain
} = require('electron');` include ipcMain in main file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I think the issue was that since I'm using VSCode, I had to first set debugging launch options so that it recognized the debug session not as a node session but as an electron session, which will cause VScode to recognize electron's sub methods (such as app, BrowserWindow, etc.) in the debugger.  Without doing that, it wasn't looking for those and was throwing an undefined error.